# set headless ubuntu linux display resolution

Tags: linux, ubuntu, display, resolution, vnc

We bought a small box as our server and we installed ubuntu linux.

We don't plug any display to it, instead, we remote desktop/vnc to the server (using TightVNC).

However, the display by default is around 1024x768 and our local display is usually much larger.

How could we change the resolution on the server without a display? Preferably, it is setup during the boot time. It is also OK to change at VNC time.

( when we plug a display, it works perfectly )

Comment: The monitor's name is showing as "Laptop" for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try creating an /etc/X11/xorg.conf file with something like:

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "VNC Device"
Driver "vesa"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "VNC Screen"
Device "VNC Device"
Monitor "VNC Monitor"
SubSection "Display"
Modes "1280x1024"
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier "VNC Monitor"
HorizSync 30-70
VertRefresh 50-75
EndSection
```

... where 1280x1024 would be replaced by the resolution you want.

I did not test it myself; this is from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8636175 (first post).

Comment: It doesn't work for me. My ubuntu is using remote desktop sharing for me to vnc. So the resolution is pre-determined at booting time. xorg.conf doesn't seem to affect the resolution so far.

Answer (score 0):

When you start the TightVNC server, one of the options is *geometry*. According to the manual page for *vncserver*, this is what determines the resolution.

> -geometry widthxheight
>   Specify the size of the VNC desktop to be created. Default is 1024x768

Comment: It doesn't work for me. My ubuntu is using remote desktop sharing for me to vnc. So the resolution is pre-determined at booting time. this "geometry" option doesn't affect the result.

Comment: "My ubuntu is using remote desktop sharing for me to vnc." Can you try to explain this in more detail? How is TightVNC started?